# How do I correctly handle buttons in different templates in web.py?

Tags: python, html, raspberry-pi, web.py

I'm trying to create a simple web interface for a raspberry pi project I'm working on.

What I want is an index page that allows me to input three values and upon clicking a button pass them to a different program on the pi that starts it's work using those values. Once the process has started, the web app should forward to a second page displaying the settings I just activated.
This second page should also provide a "STOP" Button that halts the activity of the process I started earlier, starts a different one and brings back the index page.

Everything works fine so far except for the part where I click the "STOP" button on settings.html and I get an error regarding line 32 in main.py which is supposed to validate the values entered in the fields of index.html.

This is the first time I'm using python and I'm sure I've misunderstood something about how all of this is supposed to work but I can't figure out when what code is called by which other component.

Here's the code I got so far:

**main.py**

```
import web, os
import subprocess
from web import form
render = web.template.render('templates/')

urls = (
        '/(.*)', 'index'
)

valuelimit = form.regexp(r"^-?(0|[1-9]\d*)$",'test')

input_form = form.Form(
        form.Textbox("setting1",    valuelimit, value='50', description="Setting 1"),
        form.Textbox("setting2",    valuelimit, value='70', description="Setting 2"),
        form.Textbox("setting3",  valuelimit, value='5',  description="Setting 3"),
        form.Button("OK", type="submit", description="ok")
)

stop_form = form.Form(
        form.Button("STOP", type="submit", description="ok")
)


class index:
        def GET(self,f):
                f = input_form()
                return render.index(f)

        def POST(self,f):
                f = input_form()
                a = stop_form()
                if not f.validates():
                        return render.valueerror()
                else:
                        subprocess.Popen([start process using Setting 3])
                        subprocess.Popen([start process2 using Setting 1+2])
                        return render.settings(f,a)

class settings:
        def POST(self,a):
                f = input_form()
                subprocess.Popen([stop process2])
                subprocess.Popen([start different process])
                return render.index(f)

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = web.application(urls, globals())
        app.run()
```

**index.html**

```
$def with(f)

<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Title
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <center>
            <form method="POST">
                $:f.render()
            </form>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

**settings.html**

```
$def with(f, a)

<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Title
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <center>
            Setting 1: $f.setting1.value<br>
            Setting 2: $f.setting2.value<br>
            Setting 3: $f.setting3.value<br>

            <form method="POST">
                $:a.render()
            </form>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide the actual error?